# Terraria anti-gravity potion

Tags: terraria-console

I am trying to use the Anti gravity potion to go to the sky plain in Terr-aria. I have 2:40 time left and my character won flip. How do i flip my character on the Xbox 360?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](http://www.xboxachievements.com/forum/showthread.php?t=436589) is saying up on the left stick to go upside down, and down to return to normal.  Try that, and if it doesn't work, try up on the D-pad.

Comment: Up on dpad will make it use whatever is on the up on dpad

Comment: Would that in this case drink the potion or trigger the effect?  It's been a while since I last played Terraria

Comment: it's whatever you put on the dpad for quick access so you can easily use